# How to read an equivalence of open sentences

Tags: logic

It is well-known that $(x+1)(x-1)=0 \iff x=-1~\text{or}~x=1$. Does this mean that the open sentences $(x+1)(x-1)=0$ and $x=-1~\text{or}~x=1$ are equivalent because they have the same truth set $\{-1,1\}$?

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense (assuming the universe is a [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(ring_theory))). Do you doubt something?

Comment: Thank you for asking. Not really. I'm just trying to figure out a reason behind the equivalence.

Comment: This question is best to be transferred to Philosophy SE; it is related to a question what Kit Fine calls "antinomy of the variable" in his [The Role of Variables](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3655524).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The statements $$\forall x\;\;(x+1)(x-1)=0$$ and $$\forall
     x\;\;\big(x=-1\:\:\text{or}\:\: x=1\big)$$ have the same truth *value* (false), so they are equivalent to each other; i.e., $$\forall x\;\;(x+1)(x-1)=0 \iff \forall x\;\;\big(x=-1\:\:\text{or}\:\: x=1\big).\tag A$$
- The open formulae $$(x+1)(x-1)=0\tag1$$ and
  $$x=-1\:\:\text{or}\:\: x=1\tag2$$ have the same truth *set*, so, **for each $x,$** they are equivalent to each other; i.e., $$\forall x\;\Big(x+1)(x-1)=0\iff \big(x=-1\:\:\text{or}\:\:x=1\big)\Big).\tag B$$

When $(1)$ and $(2)$ are said to be equivalent to each other (typically in the context of solving equations), the intended meaning is $(\mathrm{B})$—because the universal quantifier has been informally dropped—rather than the weaker $(\mathrm{A}).$

On the other hand, $$x=x\iff y=y$$ doesn't require a universal quantification because both open formulae $x=x$ and $y=y$ have a *fixed* truth value.

Comment: May I ask, what is the reason behind the writing $(x-1)(x+1)=0 \iff x=1~\text{or}~x=-1$, since it appears rather commonly. Does it just mean that the truth sets are the same?

Comment: @KHOOS I've just revised the answer!

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Given two formulas $\phi,\psi$ with free variables in $X$ with $x\in X$ taking a value in the set $D_x$, they are equivalent if and only if for any *valuation* $\sigma : X \to \bigcup_{x\in X}D_x$ (that is $\sigma x \in D_x$), $\phi_\sigma \iff \psi_\sigma$, where $\xi_\sigma$ is $\xi$ in which each variable $x$ has been substituted by its value $\sigma x$.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this.

Comment: Is this answer actually saying that they are equivalent because $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: [(x+1)(x-1) = 0 \Leftrightarrow (x = -1 \lor x = 1)]$?

Comment: @Hermis14 yes, basically